# Virtualenv <Environmentname> does only create but not start the Environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

Its always installs a new environment but does not go into this environment. It also does not matter whether my Environment exists bevor using the command (`virtualenv venv`). This is all that my console shows:

```
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\...\\python36-32'
New python executable in 
C:\Users\...\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

There is no

`(venv)_` -line after Installation as often described in tutorials.

Comment: Yes. That is what the command does. What is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot about that: I want to be IN the environment after setting it up. So after installation I would like to use my virtual environment to do a flask tutorial.

Comment: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#activate-script

Comment: After entering the directory have you ran `source bin/activate`?

Comment: Yeah I did use "source bin/activate", but I think I got it now, thanks to @DanielRoseman`s link :D for some weird reason in my bash "source venv/Scripts/activate" activates the environment, it seems to be a frankenstein-command between the linux and windows command, idk.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielRoseman

Comment: `mkvirtualenv` from [tag:virtualenvwrapper] does that automatically.